# Функция сравнения массивов выдаёт true для отличающихся массивов

Tags: javascript

При таком коде функция возвращает `true`:

```
function areArraysSame(array1, array2) {
    if (array1.length !== array2.length) {
        return;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        if (array1[i] !== array2[i]) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
} 
alert(areArraysSame([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2]));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нельзя возвращать `true` внутри цикла, пока еще есть непроверенные элементы массивов.

```js
function areArraysSame(array1, array2) {
  if (array1.length !== array2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] !== array2[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
console.log(areArraysSame([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 4]));
console.log(areArraysSame([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]));
console.log(areArraysSame([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, "3", 4]));
```

Comment: А как насчет `console.log(areArraysSame([{a : 1}], [{a : 1}]));`?

Comment: @Yaant Вы хотите углубиться в вопрос сравнения значений и ссылок?

Comment: Ну, я к тому, что возможно, такие массивы автор вопроса тоже хочет считать одинаковыми. :) Хотя, конечно, может быть и не хочет. :) Во всяком случае, эта особенность достойна быть упомянутой в ответе, как мне кажется.

Comment: Спасибо. Не заметил.

Comment: @FischerBenkovscki На здоровье. Успехов!

Answer (score 0):

многоуровневое сравнение массивов и объектов

```js
var equals = function(arr1, arr2) {
  var req = false;
  switch (arr1.constructor) {
    case Object:
      req = true;
      for (var name in arr1) {
        if (name in arr2) {
          if (arr1[name] === undefined || arr2[name] === undefined)
            if (arr1[name] === arr2[name])
              continue;
            else {
              req = false;
              break;
            }

          if (arr1[name].constructor !== arr2[name].constructor) {
            req = false;
            break;
          }

          if ([Array, Object, NodeList, HTMLCollection].indexOf(arr1[name].constructor) !== -1) {
            if (!equals(arr1[name], arr2[name])) {
              req = false;
              break;
            } else
              continue;
          }
          if (arr1[name] !== arr2[name]) {
            req = false;
            break;
          }
        } else {
          req = false;
          break;
        }
      }
      break;

    case Array:
    case NodeList:
    case HTMLCollection:
      if (arr1.length === arr2.length) {
        req = true;
        for (var i = 0, len = arr1.length; i < len && req === true; i++) {
          if (arr1[i] === undefined || arr2[i] === undefined)
            if (arr1[i] === arr2[i])
              continue;
            else {
              req = false;
              break;
            }

          if (arr1[i].constructor !== arr2[i].constructor)
            req = false;

          if ([Array, Object, NodeList, HTMLCollection].indexOf(arr1[i].constructor) !== -1) {
            if (!equals(arr1[i], arr2[i]))
              req = false;
            else
              continue;
          }
          if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i])
            req = false;

        }
      }
      break;
  }

  return req;
};

console.log(equals(
  [1, {s: 1},[1, "a", {gg: "vp"}]], 
  [1, {s: 1},[1, "a", {gg: "vp"}]]
 ));
console.log(equals(
  [1, {s: 1},[1, "a", {gg: "vp"}]], 
  [1, {s: 1},[1, "a", {gg: 1}]]
 ));
```